# Geolocator Plugin Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, plugin

Preciso pegar a localização atual do aparelho do usuário e com isso para me auxiliar estou usando o Plugin Geolocator do Xamarin, consigo obter a localização atual normalmente no meu smartphone mas pelo emulador do Google não pega a localização atual mesmo com o GPS configurado para a cidade do rio de Janeiro, e o estranho é que sempre aponta para Roma.

As permissões de localização do Android estão habilitadas e tudo configurado corretamente. Para isso usei como base esse projeto https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin.

Segue o código da minha page:

Construtor:

```
Public MapsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var position = PosicaoAtualAsync();
    map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position.Result, Distance.FromMeters(50)));
}
```

Método PosicaoAtualAsync:

```
async Task<Position> PosicaoAtualAsync()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;


        if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled && locator.IsGeolocationAvailable)
        {
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
            if (!locator.IsListening)
                await locator.StartListeningAsync(1000, 1000);

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 1000);

            if (position != null)
            {
                return new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
            }
        }

        await DisplayAlert("Ops", "Não conseguimos obter sua localização, por favor, verifique sua conexão e se o seu GPS está ativo.", "OK");
        return new Position(0, 0);

    }
```